# React/TypeScript - Type 'false | Element' is not assignable to type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am getting this error: **Type 'false | Element' is not assignable to type 'Element'.**

I am using React and TypeScript and the code looks like:

```
function App() {
    const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);
    return (
        {isSearching && <div> Hey </div>}
    )
}
```

`{isSearching && <div> Hey </div>}` is giving the above error

Can anyone please help me point out what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

React component should return a JSX. If isSearching is false, you return false and no JSX.

This should fix the problem:

```
function App() {
    const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
          {isSearching && <div> Hey </div>}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Except now ESLint should complain that you got a Fragment when you're returning only up to one element, no?

Answer (score 0):

You must have forgotten return a value in your component.

```
function App() {
    const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);

    return isSearching ? (<div> Hey </div>) : null
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue. Now the error is `Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2322)`